# MySQL Query: retrieve information from two tables without having to do two queries

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have two tables in my database, and I would like to retrieve information from both of them without having to do two queries.  Basically, the user_ID(s) retrieved from the tasks table needs to be used to get those respective user(s) names from the users table.  This is what I have so far, but the query is returning false:

```
SELECT t.user_id, t.nursery_ss, t.nursery_ws, t.greeter, t.date
   u.user_first_name, u.user_last_name
   FROM tasks_tbl AS t
   INNER JOIN users_tbl AS u ON t.user_id = u.user_id
   WHERE t.date = '2009-11-29'
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the WHERE clause?  By 'returning false' do you mean the query isn't returning any results?

Comment: Query looks good. Try to remove `WHERE t.date = '2009-11-29'` and see the result. May be there is not such data in DB

Comment: Post the output of `DESCRIBE TASKS_TBL`

Comment: Here's the exact error I am getting: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'u.user_first_name, u.user_last_name FROM tasks_tbl AS t INNER JOIN users_tbl' at line 1

Comment: Removing the WHERE clause had no effect.
Adding the STR_TO_DATE function had no effect.
Changing the SELECT ... to SELECT * had no effect.
I think the problem is related to getting the names from the users_tbl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot a comma after `t.date` in your select-list:

```
SELECT t.user_id, t.nursery_ss, t.nursery_ws, t.greeter, t.date -- comma needed here
   u.user_first_name, u.user_last_name
FROM tasks_tbl AS t
INNER JOIN users_tbl AS u ON t.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE t.date = '2009-11-29'
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your query looks good; you might try checking to see if other aspects of the query are faulty.  For example, try just a SELECT * from your join as specified.  Or try omitting your WHERE clause; you'll get more data than you want, but it may help you debug your query.